# Social-networking: Hadoop, HBase, Spark over MongoDB or Postgres?

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, hadoop, apache-spark, bigdata

I am architecting a social-network, incorporating various features, many powered by big-data intensive workloads (such as Machine Learning). E.g.: recommender systems, search-engines and time-series sequence matchers.

Given that I currently have 5< users—but forsee significant growth—what metrics should I use to decide between:

- Spark (with/without HBase over Hadoop)
- MongoDB or Postgres

Looking at Postgres as a means of reducing porting pressure between it and Spark (use a SQL abstraction layer which works on both). Spark seems quite interesting, can imagine various ML, SQL and Graph questions it can be made to answer speedily. MongoDB is what I usually use, but I've found its scaling and map-reduce features to be quite limiting.

Comment: All of these technologies scale well to 5+ users :). It is probably best to go with what you know best. In this stage feature development is way more important than scaling. That said, Spark is indeed great for batch processing.

Comment: @DanielDarabos: I couldn't disagree more. Choosing the wrong technology just because it is familiar may cost you big time in later stages of the development. Ask Facebook, I _know_ they can tell you some stories confirming that. Furthermore, as a developer, you should use the right tool for the job instead of banging in a nail with a screwdriver.

Comment: My impression is that this project is at the prototyping stage. Whatever is written now will get thrown away anyway. You can make better technical decisions _after_ this stage, when you understand the requirements more clearly. This is my opinion, but of course I did not write Facebook :).

Comment: I'd prefer to use this opportunity to learn a technology stack best suited to solving this problem. The Facebook example is a good one. So to answer my stack question, what should I go with?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are on the right direction to search for software stack/architecture which can:

- handle different types of load: batch, real time computing etc.
- scale in size and speed along with business growth
- be a live software stack which are well maintained and supported
- have common library support for domain specific computing such as machine learning, etc.

To those merits, Hadoop + Spark can give you the edges you need. Hadoop is relatively mature for now to handle large scale data in a batch manner. It supports reliable and scalable storage(HDFS) and computation(Mapreduce/Yarn). With the addition of Spark, you can leverage storage (HDFS) plus real-time computing (performance) added by Spark.

In terms of development, both systems are natively supported by Java/Scala. Library support, performance tuning of those are abundant here in stackoverflow and everywhere else. There are at least a few machine learning libraries(Mahout, Mlib) working with hadoop, spark.

For deployment, AWS and other cloud provider can provide host solution for hadoop/spark. Not an issue there either.

Comment: Thanks, I should note that I am using Python (which I know is also supported by Spark and has various wrappers over various Hadoop projects). How well does it handle low-latency queries? - Scaled down to 1 node (at first). - I noticed some graph and SQL support, as well as talks about moving between paradigms + the advantages that brings. - Can you elaborate?

Comment: With Python, to Hadoop, it's mostly streaming interface where data is passed in to stdin of Python code and result is sent to stdout for framework to shuffle or reduce. With Spark, via wrappers or Python FFI, data could be queried in similar way as Java does. Spark's data handling interface is very functional-programming like. :) Python programmers should feel home. There are various performance benchmark comparing spark (~100x faster) and Hadoop. That'll have to be tested on your own dataset. Overall, both systems should work well with single node and provide long term scalability in future.

Comment: Thanks, up voted. For the generic CRUD stuff should I use Spark's SQL, and for the social-networking components Spark's GraphX and for the analytics MLib, Mahout &etc.? - Or am I over-simplifying/complicating it?

Comment: Yes. My understanding is that's general guideline. With different dialects of processing language, it's easy to work with external system/data or leverage existing skills of team. Underneath the cover, data structure is mostly RDD in Spark. This architecture helps to build a heterogeneous system to interact with external source or systems a lot easier.

Comment: Thanks, just awarded you the bounty. Still reviewing other answers though, e.g.: what are your thoughts on what @suiterdev said about not using Spark as the generic CRUD layer?

Comment: Thanks A.T.! My take of CRUD of Spark is this: Spark's power is to query "Big Data" at fast speed. The core data structure - RDD is resilient(in other words -"read only"). If RDD is to be updated, all the cached related RDDs need to be recalculated. That's why ETL+ machine learning/recommendation are suited for Spark. Once ETL data is in, the input may not change during iterative processing. If input changes, the calculation needs to restart. I guess that's why mixing CRUD of "small" data with Big Data analytics may look awkward.

Comment: So what should I use for my generic CRUD layer? - Something HBase based, such as vanilla HBase, Phoenix, or something else on HDFS such as Impala or Cascading (e.g.: Lingual is fully ANSI SQL compliant)? - How do I pick between them? - [and should I ask this in a new StackOverflow question?!]

Comment: I would echo other answers' point. Once the analytics stack is set, you may add a different storage system to address your CRUD needs. for example, a RDBMS such as Mysql could provide strong support of ACID. while no-sqls give you the scalability and availability with less consistency. Since Spark/Hadoop has connectors to different types of data, it would interoperate with other storage solutions. At end of day, the nature/usage pattern of data may be the key to decide where those data reside.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should separate data storage and data processing. In particular, "Spark or MongoDB?" is not a good thing to ask, but rather "Spark or Hadoop or Storm?" and also "MongoDB or Postgres or HDFS?"

In any case, I would refrain from having the database do processing.

Comment: So I was investigating HBase with Phoenix. Also about the separation, I agree logically but am in two minds about physically. Wouldn't it be better to store all data within the one layer, e.g.: HDFS? - Or is the speed just not there? - Can I think of Spark as that speedy layer atop?

Comment: Say by whatever process data ends up in your HDFS. That's nice, but you want to *do* something with the data, right? HDFS does not provide you with processing, just with a way to access data quickly. Maybe if you can share an actual use case ("Machine Learning" is not a use case), it is easier for us to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: "recommender systems, search-engines and time-series sequence matchers.", for example optimising conference times across 10,000+ prospective attendees based off their individual planners/calendars.

Comment: 10,000 is not exactly a big number, I'd say. In particular, when using HDFS, I guess all data might fit into one HDFS block, which means you can't exploit data locality well. But say your application uses PostgreSQL, then you could use Spark's JdbcRDD to import the data from there and then use RDD operations to compute your results. But check on Spark's computing model first to see whether they match the computations you want to do and whether you need its distributedness.

Comment: Given `n=10000` and `r=17472` (half-hour slots per year) then the [naïve] time-complexity is $\mathcal{O}(nr)$. I.e.: `17,472,000`. I may be able to get $\mathcal{O}(n \log r)$ if not $\log \log$ from reading the literature on sequence matching, however this is uncertain. Regardless you can now see it as a Big Data problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have to admit that I'm a little biased but if you want to learn something new, you have serious spare time, you're willing to read a lot, and you have the resources (in terms of infrastructure), go for HBase*, you won't regret it. A whole new universe of possibilities and interesting features open up when you can have +billions of atomic counters in real time.

*Alongside Hadoop, Hive, Spark...

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it depends more on your requirements and the data volume you will have than the number of users -which is also a requirement-. Hadoop (aka Hive/Impala, HBase, MapReduce, Spark, etc.) works fine with big amounts -GB/TB per day- of data and scales horizontally very well.

In the Big Data environments I have worked with I have always used Hadoop HDFS to store raw data and leverage the distributed file system to analyse the data with Apache Spark. The results were stored in a database system like MongoDB to obtain low latency queries or fast aggregates with many concurrent users. Then we used Impala to get on demmand analytics. The main question when using so many technologies is to scale well the  infraestructure and the resources given to each one. For example, Spark and Impala consume a lot of memory (they are in memory engines) so it's a bad idea to put a MongoDB instance on the same machine.

I would also suggest you a graph database since you are building a social network architecture; but I don't have any experience with this...

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to stay purely open-sourced? If you are going to go enterprise at some point, a lot of the enterprise distributions of Hadoop include Spark analytics bundled in.

I have a bias, but, there is also the Datastax Enterprise product, which bundles Cassandra, Hadoop and Spark, Apache SOLR, and other components together. It is in use at many of the major internet entities, specifically for the applications you mention. http://www.datastax.com/what-we-offer/products-services/datastax-enterprise

You want to think about how you will be hosting this as well.

If you are staying in the cloud, you will not have to choose, you will be able to (depending on your cloud environment, but, with AWS for example) use Spark for continuous-batch process, Hadoop MapReduce for long-timeline analytics (analyzing data accumulated over a long time), etc., because the storage will be decoupled from the collection and processing. Put data in S3, and then process it later with whatever engine you need to.

If you will be hosting the hardware, building a Hadoop cluster will give you the ability to mix hardware (heterogenous hardware supported by the framework), will give you a robust and flexible storage platform and a mix of tools for analysis, including HBase and Hive, and has ports for most of the other things you've mentioned, such as Spark on Hadoop (not a port, actually the original design of Spark.) It is probably the most versatile platform, and can be deployed/expanded cheaply, since the hardware does not need to be the same for every node.

If you are self-hosting, going with other cluster options will force hardware requirements on you that may be difficult to scale with later.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to concentrate on purely open-source. MapR does seem rather good though, as does Hortonworks… haven't looked into Datastax though. So your recommendation is to use Cassandra for generic CRUD, Solr for search, Spark for realtime analytics and Hadoop MapReduce for long-timeline analytics?

Comment: Well, it really depends on your use case. Cassandra has the fastest writes and streaming reads, but is a key-value store, similar to HBase but with a more specific implementation. Your data model may work very well for it, or something else might be better. Solr has/is gaining a fair amount of traction as search, Spark is the current go-to for near-real-time analytics, and MapReduce, or its abstractions Pig and Hive, or the variants of those like Impala, let you do conventional DBMS-feeling operations at scale economically.

Comment: Okay, well if I was choosing between Cassandra and Spark for my generic CRUD components, how would I make my choice? - Nothing is wrong with Solr, ElasticSearch and Luscene, but I'm in no rush to add search to my project so I'll leave that to one side for now. - Transaction support would be nice, but at the end of the day I doubt I'll require that across many components.

Comment: Like I said, depends on your use case, which should determine your data model, which will steer your ingestion method, which should steer your storage. Honestly, the way these stacks are built, everything is loosely coupled, so you can swap things around. To answer the immediate comment, Spark isn't really a collection method. You write Spark code to make data into information. So, not the C at all. Cassandra is a solid choice for a key-value store. So is HBase. A columnar store might work better for you. Or maybe a ORM store. Can't make that call until your data model is more developed.

Comment: So let's talk about the most simple models that are extremely generic. Authentication and user profiles. Store access tokens in Redis. The models shouldn't be in Spark, is that what you're saying? - So I should use HBase or Cassandra for that?

Comment: Spark is processing, like faster Map/Reduce. Not storage. You still need a collection tier, and storage/organization tier. If you can model your data in sparse columnar form, key-value or nested key-value abstractions, then Cassandra is durable and fast, but needs hardware all the same, so, good for hosted solutions like AWS or others. There is a Docker image also. HBase has more failure possible due to master/slave design, but more hardware flexibility. This would be your storage/organization tier. For collection, you need something too, like, HTTP POST -> Storm/Kafka.

Answer (score 1):

We use Spark +Hbase + Apache Phoenix + Kafka +ElasticSearch and scaling has been easy so far.

*Phoenix is a JDBC driver for Hbase, it allows to use java.sql with hbase, spark (via JDBCrdd) and ElasticSearch (via JDBC river), it really simplifies integration.

Comment: Interesting. Can you expand on your use-case, and maybe include some latency benchmarks for common (CRUD), realtime analytics, search, batch analytics and similar? - Also I should note that I am using Python rather than a language on the JVM.

Comment: Phoenix has some performance numbers here: http://phoenix.apache.org/performance.html

Comment: I feel that I am leaning more towards Apache Phoneix nowadays. FYI: There is a library for talking to JDBC from Python.